# Maximum serialized Protobuf message size

Tags: protocol-buffers

Is there a way to get the maximal size of a certain protobuf message after it will be serialized?

I'm referring to messages that don't contain "repeated" elements.

Note that I'm *not* referring to the size of a protobuf message with a specific content, but to the *maximum possible* size that it can get to (in the worst case).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In general, any Protobuf message can be any length due to the possibility of unknown fields.

If you are *receiving* a message, you cannot make any assumptions about the length.

If you are *sending* a message that you built yourself, then you can perhaps assume that it only contains fields you know about -- but then again, you can also easily compute the exact message size in this case.

Thus it's *usually* not useful to ask what the maximum size is.

With that said, you could write code that uses the `Descriptor` interfaces to iterate over the `FieldDescriptor`s for a message type (`MyMessageType::descriptor()`).

See: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor

Similar interfaces exist in Java, Python, and probably others.

Here's the rules to implement:

Each field is composed of a tag followed by some data.

For the tag:

- Field numbers 1-15 have a 1-byte tag.
- Field numbers 16 and up have 2-byte tags.

For the data:

- `bool` is always one byte.
- `int32`, `int64`, `uint64`, and `sint64` have a maximum data length of 10 bytes (yes, `int32` can be 10 bytes if it is negative, unfortunately).
- `sint32` and `uint32` have a maximum data length of 5 bytes.
- `fixed32`, `sfixed32`, and `float` are always exactly 4 bytes.
- `fixed64`, `sfixed64`, and `double` are always exactly 8 bytes.
- Enum-typed fields' maximum length depends on the maximum enum value:

  - 0-127: 1 byte
  - 128-16384: 2 bytes
  - ... it's 7 bits per byte, but hopefully your enum isn't THAT big!
  - Also note that negative values will be encoded as 10 bytes, but hopefully there aren't any.
- Message-typed fields' maximum length is the maximum length of the message type plus bytes for the length prefix. The length prefix is, again, one byte per 7 bits of integer data.
- Groups (which you shouldn't be using; they're a decrepit old feature deprecated before protobuf was even released publicly) have a maximum size equal to the maximum size of the contents plus a second field tag (see above).

If your message contains any of the following, then its maximum length is unbounded:

- Any field of type `string` or `bytes`. (Unless you know their max length, in which case, it's that max length plus a length prefix, like with sub-messages.)
- Any repeated field. (Unless you know its max length, in which case, each element of the list has a max length as if it were a free-standing field, including tag. There is NO overall length prefix here. Unless you are using `[packed=true]`, in which case you'll have to look up the details.)
- Extensions.

Comment: Are you sure `int32` can take up to 10 bytes if negative ? AFAIK any int32 encoded using varint can be encoded using maximum 5 bytes.

Comment: @tigrou Yes I'm sure, since I wrote the code. :) Negative int32s have to be padded to 10 bytes because int32s are expected to be forwards-compatible with int64s, so that you can change an existing int32 field to int64 in the future if you need to.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there is no feature to calculate the maximum size in Google's own protobuf.

[Nanopb generator](https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb/blob/master/generator/nanopb_generator.py#L462) computes the maximum size when possible and exports it as a `#define` in the generated file.

It is also quite simple to calculate manually for small messages, based on the [protobuf encoding documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding).

Comment: Awesome! Would have been great if there was something that can do this in runtime, but I guess compile time would do... Gonna try that Python script next week and see if does the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

While implementing protobuffer 3 message size calculation, I found that most of what Kenton said is true. I did run into one oversight though: Tags are created from the field number, which is left-shifted 3 bits, then bit-wise ORed with the wire type (found in wire_format_lite.h). That result is then encoded as a `var int`. So for Tags that are just over 16, the tag will be 2 bytes, but if the field number is larger (>~1000) then the tag will be larger than 3 bytes. This probably isn't a problem for protobuffer 3 users, since having a field number that large is a misuse of protobuf.