# create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB

Tags: python, tensorflow

I created a ndarray (W) which size is (2^22, 256), and I tried to use this array as my initialization of weight matirx using:

```
w = tf.Variable(tf.convert_to_tensor(W))
```

then, the tensorflow raised a error:
*ValueError: Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB.*

How can I fix this problem?
PS. my weight matrix must using that (2^22, 256) matrix for initializing.
THX :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Protobuf has a [hard limit of 2GB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34186672/7443104). And 2^22*256 floats are 4GB. Your problem is, that you are going to embed the initial value into the graph-proto by

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

w_init = np.random.randn(2**22, 256).astype(np.float32)
w = tf.Variable(tf.convert_to_tensor(w_init))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print sess.run(tf.reduce_sum(w))
```

causing

```
ValueError: Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB.
```

This graph definition above is basically saying: "The graph has a variable occupying 4GB and here are the exact values: ..."

Instead, you should write

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

w_init = np.random.randn(2**22, 256).astype(np.float32)
w_plhdr = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[2**22, 256])
w = tf.get_variable('w', [2**22, 256])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(w.assign(w_plhdr), {w_plhdr: w_init})
    print sess.run(tf.reduce_sum(w))
```

This way, your variable holds 4GB of value but the graph only has the knowledge: "Hey, there is a variable of size 4 GB. Just don't care about the exact values within the graph definition. Because there is an operation to overwrite these values anyway later.".

Comment: Hello Patwie, thank you for your comments.
I tired what you said above, but another error raised:
InternalError: Could not allocate ndarray
Could you please give me more advice?

Comment: This work perfectly fine here. Enough RAM available?

Comment: OK, it was not enough RAM. I reduced the dimension of my matrix (but make sure that larger than 2GB), it worked! Thank you again! :)

Answer (score -2):

for tf v1.14.0 you can solve this with tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
tf v2.0+ doesn't throw error in situation at all.