# Truncated protobufs in Micronaut application

Tags: java, microservices, protocol-buffers, netty, micronaut

I have a Micronaut (version 2.1.4) application that consumes Protobuf messages via HTTP.

This is the controller example:

```
@Post
@Consumes(ProtobufferCodec.PROTOBUFFER_ENCODED)
@Produces(ProtobufferCodec.PROTOBUFFER_ENCODED)
public HttpResponse<MyResponse> ingestData(@Body byte[] body)
  throws InvalidProtocolBufferException {

        MyProto myOjbect = MyProto.parseFrom(body);
        MyResponse responseBody = myService.processData(body);
        return HttpResponse.ok(responseBody);
}
```

My problem is that, **only for some requests** (not all of them), the line `MyProto.parseFrom(body)` raises an exception

```
om.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.  This could mean either that the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length.
    at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.truncatedMessage(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:84)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream$ArrayDecoder.pushLimit(CodedInputStream.java:1189)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream$ArrayDecoder.readMessage(CodedInputStream.java:886)
    ...
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:158)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:191)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:203)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:208)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:48)
....
```

And **the exception is right, the body (byte[]) came truncated (not complete) and with a different length** from the one, I've sent via CURL. I also verified that the value coming in the `Content-Length` header is different from the length of the `byte[]` (protobuf), in the way that the length of the `byte[]` is smaller.

I'm not able to reproduce this issue, only happens in production.

Any idea?

"Feelings":

- It happens with big requests
- Maybe Netty has some parameter that, even if the request is allowed by size, it's truncated, chopped, or similar and that affects the protobuf (byte[])
- Performance (memory) problems?

More information:

- io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:2.1.4
- io.micronaut:micronaut-http-server-netty
- io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-protobuff-support:1.0.1

Comment: Netty _does_ have default max lengths for request bodies -- got bit by this once in a Spring app. I don't know anything about micronaut though. :(

Comment: Perhaps the request comes in "chunked" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)

Comment: @Rody but, in such a case, should I get a error, warn or some kind of exception? Or the Netty just cut/truncates the body?

Comment: I would recommend installing "Charles Proxy". I've used it personally for years. It's super useful for debugging exactly this kind of thing. It's a proxy server where you can see all the requests and responses in a nice clear and simple way. You can also edit and replay requests which makes fixing things a lot easier.

Comment: @Lobo Are you using any reverse proxy? Could you also provide more details on Content-Length for which this fails? (I know you said you can't reproduce this, but if were able to get a log which states the `content-length > byte[]`)

Comment: I would look for `content-type`. May be it's not what you expect for some requests. May it's gzipped or something when server doesn't support it.

Comment: @NagarajTantri we saw that, indeed, the value in the content length is different (higher than) from the byte[] length. Yes, we have a reverse proxy, but we were able to discard the problem is the proxy (NGINX)